# Variations- Creating A Unique URL for Variations

Tags: magento-enterprise

I'm trying to get variation products to Google Shopping and per their requirement, I need either static URLs for the child sku's or have the variation attribute preselected in the parent page.  How do I do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you say "variations", are you referring to Configurable products?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Configurable products, you should look at an extension that handles those feeds for you. I'm looking into this as well and from what I can tell, Wyomind's extension looks the best.

https://www.wyomind.com/google-shopping-magento.html

https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/advanced-product-feeds-generator.html

Comment: You should test what happens with `core_url_rewrite` table after installing this. Basically, do a reindex of URL rewrites, get a count of the number of records. Then again a reindex of URL rewrites and the count should be the same. If not, you're in trouble and need to verify uniqueness of URL keys in all products.